# c# - Polly how to persist retry chains

Tags: c#, kubernetes, polly

We are considering to use Polly as our failover lib.

We run our applications in a kubernetes environment. We can't guarantee that the pods that for example are running retry attempts against a certain service will live long enough for the request to be successful. And if the pod dies the retry chain disappears forever I guess.

How do you deal with that scenario? It is important for us that certain retry chains always continue until success.

Comment: You may need to push the retries out to an external asynchronous work queue or some other external store/trigger mechanism of some kind. If in Azure, [Azure Durable functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview) may offer an approach?

Answer (score 3):

Polly is an in-process library and doesn't currently offer any out-of-process retry co-ordination. There is no current option to persist Polly retry state anywhere out-of-process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is what I suspected. Im thinking that I will persist unfinished requests in a redis cache or similar and then have some other process to finish them of.